Why are python timezone.utc and ZoneInfo("UTC") not equivalent tzinfo objects? How to check they are the same TZ?
Why are these not equal?
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfoNotFoundError

>>> dt_tz = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
>>> dt_zi = dt_tz.astimezone(tz=ZoneInfo("UTC"))

>>> dt_tz
datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 1, 23, 15, 24, 3560, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> dt_zi
datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 1, 23, 15, 24, 3560, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC'))

>>> dt_tz == dt_zi
True
>>> dt_tz.tzinfo == dt_zi.tzinfo
False

How is it possible to check that two datetime tz-aware objects have an equivalent TZ, if they are created with either timezone or ZoneInfo?  At first sight, these things intend to do the same stuff but they are not entirely inter-operable.  For example, there is no ZoneInfo.astimezone() conversion.
In anticipation of answers that recommend using some third-party library, those answers are OK but the strong preference is to use python builtin packages (python 3 >= 3.11).
One Approach
>>> dt_tz.tzname()
'UTC'
>>> dt_zi.tzname()
'UTC'
>>> dt_tz.tzname() == dt_zi.tzname()
True
>>> dt_tz.tzinfo
datetime.timezone.utc
>>> type(dt_tz.tzinfo)
<class 'datetime.timezone'>
>>> ZoneInfo(dt_tz.tzname())
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='UTC')

BUT this doesn't generalize beyond UTC :(
>>> dt_ny = datetime.now().astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
>>> dt_ny
datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 1, 19, 38, 53, 69087, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/New_York'))
>>> ts = dt_ny.isoformat()
>>> ts
'2024-05-01T19:38:53.069087-04:00'
>>> ts_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(ts)
>>> ts_dt
datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 1, 19, 38, 53, 69087, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
>>> ts_dt.tzname()
'UTC-04:00'
>>> ZoneInfo(ts_dt.tzname())

zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key UTC-04:00'


I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that the time returned by both checks is different, since you're calling for the time now each time.  This is likely not the full answer, but merely part of the issue.

This may be relevant https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/8683

As to why timezone.utc and ZoneInfo("UTC") are not considered equal: they are instances of different classes, and the objects are of different origin.

zoneinfo.ZoneInfo queries the IANA tz database on your system (src). Try find /usr/share/zoneinfo -name "UTC" on a Linux or Mac. On Windows, the IANA db needs to be installed separately via the tzdata package.
datetime.timezone.utc is a predefined instance of a timezone class object, with an offset of zero and the name field set to UTC (src).

Comparison of timezones (as in "timezone rules") is a more delicate matter, which depends on your needs. Given two datetimes, you could for instance

compare the actual timezone (rules), i.e. if two datetimes both "belong" in tz X, with X being a IANA db identifier:

from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

chi = datetime(2024,1,1,tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Chicago"))
ny = datetime(2024,1,1,tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))

print(chi.tzinfo.key == ny.tzinfo.key) # note: ZoneInfo objects required as tzinfo!
# False

ny2 = datetime(2025,7,11,tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
print(ny2.tzinfo.key == ny.tzinfo.key)
# True

# note: that is still a simplification.
# "America/New_York" would be != "US/Eastern" which would be incorrect;
# US/Eastern is just an old/obsolete identifier, but still in the db
# and linking to "America/New_York"


compare just the offsets from UTC, i.e. the datetime fields (hours minuts etc.) are directly comparable:

print(chi.utcoffset() == ny.utcoffset())
# False

some_dt = datetime.fromisoformat("2024-01-01T00:00-06:00")
print(chi.utcoffset() == some_dt.utcoffset())
# True


you could also compare only the datetime fields, to see if two wall clocks would indicate the same time:

print(chi.replace(tzinfo=None) == some_dt.replace(tzinfo=None))
# True


Note that for case #1, you might need to write tz package-specific code, i.e. check if the tzinfo has a timezone from pytz, dateutil etc.
